# getFetchSize() and next() methods of ResultSet

Tags: oracle, jdbc

How `getFetchSize()` and  `next()` methods of ResultSet are not giving the same result?, as you can see a getFetchSize comes as 7 but while loop contents are not printing.

```
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(7);
    System.out.println("resultSet::::::::::::::getFetchSize::>>>>>" + resultSet.getFetchSize());
    int i = 1;
    while (resultSet.next())
         {
               System.out.println("inside while loop:" + i);
         }
System.out.println("finished");
```

**Output:**

```
resultSet::::::::::::::getFetchSize::>>>>> 10
finished
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getFetchSize()` doesn't tell you how large the resultset is - this information is generally not known in advance - but the size of the internal buffer that is used to fetch the results. In this case, the JDBC driver would fetch 10 result rows at once, delivering them one-by-one when you call `next()`.

Obviously, that doesn't mean there will really be 10 results.